# Why does texture binding require non-const device pointers?

Tags: c++, cuda, textures

I'm using `cudaTextureObject_t` do do some linear interpolation. For binding to the lookup data array to the texture object I've got to provide `void *devPtr`, as defined in `driver_types.h`. I'm curious why that's not a `const void *devPtr`? Since this data is for looking up values I don't expect CUDA to modify it. I certainly can make things work with creating casting, just curious.

Comment: What functions are you using? Can you show a snippet?

Answer (score 3):

The generic [cudaResourceDesc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaResourceDesc.html#structcudaResourceDesc) which is passed to [`cudaCreateTextureObject()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT_1g16ac75814780c3a16e4c63869feb9ad3) does indeed take a

```
void * devPtr
```

However the same generic resource descriptor is used for [surface objects](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT_1g958899474ab2c5f40d233b524d6c5a01) as well.  So it cannot be `const` for that usage.  Surfaces are a writable (from CUDA kernel code) resource.